# MathType originated {\lim}\limits_{...} producing error in TeX

Tags: math-mode

[image: {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty }]
above equation is produced in MathType 6
and when I copy it (in Collaborize Mode) it gives me following notation

```
 {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty }
```

Google Charts Api converting it correctly. ([click here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chs=1x0&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chco=000000&chl=%7B%5Clim%20%7D%5Climits_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%20%7D)).
But when I try to convert it in TexLive it gives me following error:
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.

I know equation can be created by \lim \limits_{x \to \infty } .
But what is the problem in MathType notation.

Tex file code for reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{displaymath}
 {\lim}\limits_{x \to \infty }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As the error message says `Limit controls must follow a math operator`, and enclosing `\lim` in braces makes an ordinary atom. That's TeX `:-)`

Comment: It's the brace pair around `lim` giving you the trouble. But `\limits` is not needed here anyways. This is just typical junk TeX code that software produces.

Comment: And [welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917)

Comment: @percusse But google API can produce the correct image

Comment: That's probably using MathJax but not TeX.

Comment: @percusse That is possible :)

Comment: The real question ought to be: "Why on earth does MathType6 place an unneeded -- and, in fact, erroneous and counterproductive -- pair of curly braces around `\lim`? If Google's Charts API renders`{\lim}` correctly, the main conclusion one should draw is that Charts API is buggy (or sloppy, or both, *not* that `{\lim}` is syntactically valid. You should raise your question with the maintainer(s) of MathType. Your question is off-topic for this site, I'm afraid.